# Error : Use of fullScreenIntent requires the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0

I'm using notifications with fullscreen my code works find in `Oreo` and below version 
But when i'm running `android-Q` I'm getting below exception

```
Use of fullScreenIntent requires the USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT permission
```

I'm using [**`setFullScreenIntent()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)) for notifications with fullscreen

Here is my code

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "123");

notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("Test")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

mNotificationManager.notify(1000, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the answer

Now wee need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />` permission in manifest file

> [**Permissions changes for fullscreen intents**](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes-q#full-screen-intents)

Apps that target Android Q or higher and use notifications with fullscreen intents must request the [`USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT) permission in their app's manifest file. This is a [normal permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal-dangerous), so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx.xxx.xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'm developing a ride hailing app, should I use fullScreenIntent for the RideRequest
So should I use drawOverOtherApps permission and open the activity directly?

My activity already has all the UI elements to show the new ride request.

Answer (score 0):

setFullScreenIntent

An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status bar. Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call or alarm clock that the user has explicitly set to a particular time. If this facility is used for something else, please give the user an option to turn it off and use a normal notification, as this can be extremely disruptive.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder